# jQuery dynamic container width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var screen_size=$(window).width();

if(screen_size<1200 && screen_size>=1000)
{
$("#container").width(1000);
}
else if(screen_size>=1900)
{
$("#container").width(1400);
}

});
```

I decided to create a container with 1200px width, which is resize in some cases according to user resolution (width actually). This code works good but I want to ask if this is a good way to do that kind of operation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why you don't use CSS3 media queries?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Yeah, I know about CSS3 media but I thought that I could try do this with jQuery, so you think that CSS3 media queries are more proper?

Comment: Yes, Media queries is a more standard way and give you better performance and user experience specially on mobile devices, But it may lack in browser compatibility.

Comment: I think the best solution is using CSS media queries with Javascript fallback. [This library](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that's better done with media queries perhaps

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 1000px){
    #container{
        width:1000px;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1900px){
    #container{
        width:1400px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 Media queries to achieve this. You can go through this links to understand it
[Link1](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp), [Link2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), [Link3](http://cssmediaqueries.com/)

You can do something like this to set screen

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1000px) and (max-device-width : 1200px) and (orientation : landscape) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code in your example you should definitely go with media queries in CSS as this is a pure style problem. However, if you still would want to go the behavioral way, let's say if you need to trigger other behavior based on screen size, you should use window.matchMedia in order to reuse your media queries to dictate your "adaptive behavior". This is very useful in scenarios where your behavioral components in javascript need to react differently on certain media.

I've created a small example:
http://jsbin.com/wawey/1/edit